# reading in multiple text files

Tags: string, file-io

I have a code:

```
`int main() {
 int year;

for (year=1880; year<=2011; year++) {
stringstream ss;
ss << year;

string birth = ss.str();

ifstream yob("yob"birth".txt");
}


}`
```

I want to read in 130 text files with this for loop, and each text file looks like "yob1880.txt" or "yob1975.txt" etc. I know that that ifstream yob("yob"birth".txt") doesn't work I just wanted to illustrate what I wanted to do. How can I add the string "yob" to string year and string ".txt"?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use a `stringstream`. You can then build a string and call `ss.str()` on it to retrieve the string.
E.g.,

```
std::stringstream ss;
int n = 5;
ss << "file" << n << ".txt";
std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
```

This will write `file5.txt` to standard out.

Edit: Just checked the docs, and it looks like std::ifstream takes a C string, not a `std::string`, so you should call `c_str()` on the resulting string, e.g.,

```
std::ifstream file(ss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: so how do I input the file? ifstream file(ss.str().c_str()) doesn't work. When I try to cout the file after reading it into an array it won't work

Comment: How are you trying to print the file?